VueJS leaflet fitBounds not working without timeout
I have an issue with leaflet in VueJS 3. I'm creating a leaflat map with markers, but I have to use a setTimeout-function to make the fitBounds() work. Without the setTimeout I see the map with zoomlevel 0 (Complete world). Currently my code looks like this to create the leaflet map:
setup(props, { emit }) {
        onMounted( () => {

            const defLatitude = props.visitData.visitgpslatitude;
            const defLongitude = props.visitData.visitgpslongitude;


            var maps = L.map("mapContainer");
            L.tileLayer("https://maps.omniscale.net/v2/{3}/style.default/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                maxZoom: 18
            }).addTo(maps);
            //use a mix of renderers
            var customPane = maps.createPane("customPane");
            var canvasRenderer = L.canvas({ pane: "customPane" });
            customPane.style.zIndex = 399; // put just behind the standard overlay pane which is at 400
            
            var group = L.featureGroup();

            group.addTo(maps);




            //Visit icon
            var visitIcon = L.divIcon({
                className: "marker-visit",
                iconSize: [25, 41],
                iconAnchor: [10, 44],
                popupAnchor: [3, -40]
            });
            const visitMarker = new L.Marker([defLatitude, defLongitude], {icon: visitIcon});
            visitMarker.addTo(group);

            if(props.taskData != null) {
                for(var i = 0; i < props.taskData.length; i++) {
                    const task = props.taskData[i];
                    var numberIcon = L.divIcon({
                        className: "avn-marker-task marker-task",
                        iconSize: [25, 41],
                        iconAnchor: [10, 44],
                        popupAnchor: [3, -40],
                        html: "" + (i + 1)       
                    });
                    if(typeof task.latitude != "undefined" && typeof task.longitude != "undefined") {
                        const taskMarker = new L.Marker([task.latitude,task.longitude], {icon: numberIcon});
                        group.addLayer(taskMarker);
                    }
                }
            }
            window.setInterval(function () {
                maps.invalidateSize();
            }, 2);

            setTimeout(function () {
                maps.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
            }, 3500);

            
        });        
    }

How can I get rid of the setTimeout function, to fit instantly?
Sven

Have you tried this instead of the timeout? https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick
